# Best practice for managing the cluster from the outside

Tags: kubernetes

I have a best-practice question:

I have a Django application running somewhere (non-k8s) where my end-user accounts are tracked. Separately, I have a k8s cluster that has a service for every user. When a new user signs up in Django, a new service should be created in the cluster.

What is the best practice for doing this? Two options I see are:

1. Have a long-lived service in the cluster, something like `user-pod-creator`, which exposes an API to the Django side, allowing it to ask for a pod to be created.
2. Give the Django permissions to use the cluster's API directly; have it create (and delete) pods as it wishes.

Intuitively I prefer the first because of the separation of concerns it creates and because of security reasons. But the second would give a lot of flexibility to the Django app so that it can not only create and delete pods, but it can have more visibility into the cluster if need be with direct API calls, instead of me having to expose new API endpoints in `user-pod-creator` or some other service.

Comment: I mean option 1 just moves the problem. Something needs to talk to the Kubernetes API in the end. Building a facade service can be useful if you want to apply your own authorization rules or logging and it will be used by multiple internal things. Or if you want to separate things so you can test the privileged component more extensively. But otherwise it's the same problem just in a new place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 is a valid approach and can be solved with a [service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/).

Create a [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#serviceaccount-v1-core) for your Django app:

```sh
kubectl create serviceaccount django
```

This ServiceAccount points to a Secret, and this Secret contains a token.

Find out the Secret associated with the ServiceAccount:

```sh
kubectl get serviceaccount django -o yaml
```

Get the token in the Secret:

```sh
kubectl get secret django-token-d2tz4 -o jsonpath='{.data.token}'
```

Now you can use this token as an HTTP bearer token in the Kubernetes API requests from your Django app outside the cluster.

That is, include the token in the HTTP `Authorization` header of the Kubernetes API requests like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>
```

In this way, your request passes the authentication stage in the API server. However, the service account has no permissions yet (authorisation).

You can assign the required permissions to your service account with Roles and RoleBindings:

```sh
kubectl create role django --verb <...> --resource <...>
kubectl create rolebinding django --role django --serviceaccount django
```

Regarding security: grant only the minimum permissions needed to the service account (principle of least privileges), and if you think someone stole the service account token, you can just delete the service account with `kubectl delete serviceaccount django` to invalidate the token.

See also [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) for an example of the presented approach. Especially:

> Service account bearer tokens are perfectly valid to use outside the cluster and can be used to create identities for long standing jobs that wish to talk to the Kubernetes API.